# How to listen to uninstallation event in javascript from a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome-extension, listener, uninstallation

I'm trying to clean some preferences files when a user uninstall my extension from chrome browser.

On google website, http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/external_extensions.html

They say, **"To uninstall your extension (for example, if your software is uninstalled), remove the metadata from the preferences file or registry. "**

I would really like to do that but how do my extension listens to the 'uninstall event', if it exists. I didn't find this event anywhere.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What they mean by that paragraph is if you are uninstalling your software that was bundled with the extension, you should manually uninstall the extension as well by removing registry entries.

There is an [uninstall event](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/management.html#event-onUninstalled):

```
chrome.management.onUninstalled.addListener(function(string id) {...});
```

It would work for listening to other extensions being uninstalled, but catching your own uninstall with it most likely would not be possible.

Comment: It is so true, and so unfortunate.

Comment: I'm really surprised we can listen for uninstall event on other extensions, but not on our own ones ...

Answer (score 13):

You may use "setUninstallURL" method. Once your extension is being uninstalled, it will open specified URL so that you can do something on your server.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL

Comment: This is the correct answer as of Chrome 41, although **you cannot listen** for the actual event and do other things, like cleanup.