# How to clean up web pages on Chrome extension uninstall/disable

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that inserts some mark-up into webpages. This mark-up is usually hidden by the CSS that the extension inserts.

When the user switches the extension off using the extension's browser button, I remove all mark-up using the content script. However, when the extension is uninstalled, or disabled, the mark-up is left on the webpage, but the CSS that's hiding it is uninstalled. This leaves quite a deformed webpage.

Is there any way of cleaning up this inserted mark-up before the content-script and css are removed?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably can't. You can try to play around with [`chrome.management.onUninstalled` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management), but I doubt it will be fired before the extension itself is removed.

Comment: If the user is uninstalling your extension you dont have to be that nice to them :) a simple refresh fixes it.

Comment: I wonder if injected scripts (as opposed to content scripts) are also removed when uninstalled? If not, you can play with that. Maybe your injected script sends periodic messages to the background page. When the message fails the extension is gone (thu  the message also fails if chrome autoupdated your extension)

Comment: @Xan: Thanks! Already played with the chrome.management API. It can be useful for doing cleanup after other extensions, but not on self.

Comment: @ZigMandel : Thanks! Seems like a reasonable option. Will play with it and report back. (Though, don't like the idea of using repeating timers on all pages).

Comment: How about opening a port to the background page and listening to `onDisconnected`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to listen to uninstallation event in javascript from a chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888760/how-to-listen-to-uninstallation-event-in-javascript-from-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: @lionello Thanks. That question refers to clearing preferences when the developer wants to un-install their own extension. That bit is easy, though the answer provided that using chrome.management api doesn't work in that case either.

My query was about cleaning up programmatically inserted markup on pages when the user uninstalls extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the solution I eventually went with.

Chrome has a quirk where css inserted automatically by extensions (listed in manifest) is removed when the extension is removed when the extension is uninstalled. However, css inserted programmatically by the extension is left in place.

So, I switched my css insertion from manifest to programmatic. Now, even when the user uninstalls the extension, the CSS stays on page hiding my markup. Till next page reload, when both the CSS and the markup are discarded.

Not sure this injected CSS non-removal behaviour is a feature or a bug, but it's working for now.