# After deletion of chrome extension remove some html elements from website

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Hi I am new to chrome extension. I have build the basic chrome extension and I want to install it using inline installation. I followed the following  link :

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation#already-installed

All is working properly. I want to check if extension is already installed or not so I referred the above document, whenever user install the extension at that time we are appending the new div using content script to my installation page on website. If that div is present it means the extension is already installed.

Following code is added in my content_script of chrome extension for appending the div whenever the extension is installed:

```
var isInstalledNode = document.createElement('div');
isInstalledNode.id = 'extension-is-installed';
document.body.appendChild(isInstalledNode);
```

Then my installation page can check for the presence of that DOM node, which signals that the extension is already installed:

```
if (document.getElementById('extension-is-installed')) {
  document.getElementById('install-button').style.display = 'none';
}
```

But I am facing one problem, whenever I deleted my extension from settings/extensions, still the div is present on extension's installation page.

Is their any provision to remove the div when my extension is deleted or removed from browser?

Comment: What code are you using to check if the plugin is installed?

Answer (score 0):

You can't catch the uninstallation event for your own extension, though there is an [management.onUninstalled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#event-onUninstalled), it is used for listening to other extensions/apps. See following answer for more details:
[How to listen to uninstallation event in javascript from a chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888760/how-to-listen-to-uninstallation-event-in-javascript-from-a-chrome-extension)

I just come up with two workarounds, one is creating another extension to listen to the uninstall of your first extension; another one is using [runtime.setUninstallURL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-setUninstallURL) to visit a URL upon uninstallation, you can do something in server if you want.

BTW, for `isInstalledNode`, you needn't/shouldn't set the id, since there may be other elements in the webpage with the same id, you just need to create the node and use `document.body.contains(isIntalledNode)` to check if it exists.